# could not translate host name-- Ansible/AWX

Tags: ansible

Creating dba and password

```
postgresql_db:
        name: "{{ customer_id }}"
        encoding: UTF-8
        lc_collate: en_US.UTF-8
        lc_ctype: en_US.UTF-8
        port: 5432
        template: pg_default
        state: present
        login_host: localhost
        login_user: "{{postgresql_admin_password }}"
        login_password: "{{ postgresql_admin_password  }}"
        login_unix_socket: "{{ postgresql_unix_socket_directories }}"
```

What vars should be defined in login host and login_unix_socket to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare all attributes when you call a module in a task. I propose you to ignore the `login_unix_socket` (it will be fine) and for `login_host`, just provide the «*Host running the database.*» as describe in the [`postgresql_db` module doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_db_module.html).